# Depth Band "> 1.20" isn't being extracted, could the > be affecting the extract?

Tags: pyqgis

We have created a code to extract the different bands of flood depths from the EA and it works extracting '0.00 - 0.15', '0.15 - 0.30', '0.30 - 0.60', '0.60 - 0.90', '0.90 - 1.20' ranges. However, it doesn't seem to extract the > 1.20 depth band and I've tried other methods which don't seem to be fixing it. Could someone help out with this? I will leave a link below to the data source if you want to test it out and the code after. We can't tell if we have missed out on a character which is why is isn't extracting or something wrong with another section of the code relating to the > 1.20. We are sure that the data band exists in the shapefile.

https://environment.data.gov.uk/rofsw  (SO93 Square)

Here's the code:

```py
import os
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsField, QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsFeature
import processing

#List of input shapefiles
input_shapefiles = [
r"F:\Workfile\J114\QGIS\RoFSW-SO93\2024\RoFSW_SO93_Depth_1in1000.shp",]

#Define depth bands
depth_bands = ['0.00 - 0.15', '0.15 - 0.30', '0.30 - 0.60', '0.60 - 0.90', '0.90 - 1.20', '> 1.20']

#Create a directory to store the output shapefiles
output_directory = r"F:\Workfile\J114\QGIS\RoFSW-SO93\2024\Outputs"
if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
os.makedirs(output_directory)

#Path to the clip shapefile
clip_shapefile = r"F:\Workfile\J114\QGIS\Shape Files\Wider area.shp"

#Iterate over each input shapefile
for input_shapefile in input_shapefiles:
  #Load the input shapefile
  layer = QgsVectorLayer(input_shapefile, os.path.basename(input_shapefile), "ogr")

  #Check if the layer is loaded successfully
  if not layer.isValid():
      print(f"Layer {input_shapefile} failed to load!")
      continue

  #Iterate over each depth band
  for band in depth_bands:
      # Define output shapefile name
      output_shapefile = os.path.join(output_directory, f"{os.path.basename(input_shapefile)}_depth_{band.replace(' ', '_')}.shp")
      #Filter features based on depth band
      expr = QgsField("depth").name() + f" = '{band}'" if band != '> 1.20' else QgsField("depth").name() + " > 1.20"
      subset = layer.getFeatures(expr)
      # Create output layer with CRS set to EPSG:27700
      output_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:27700", f"{os.path.basename(input_shapefile)}_depth_{band.replace(' ', '_')}", "memory")
      output_layer.startEditing()
      #Add attributes to the output layer
      output_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(layer.fields().toList())
      output_layer.updateFields()
      # Add features to the output layer
      for feature in subset:
          output_feature = QgsFeature(feature)
          output_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([output_feature])
      #Commit changes
      output_layer.commitChanges()
      # Clip the output layer with the clip shapefile
      result = processing.run("native:clip", {
          'INPUT': output_layer,
          'OVERLAY': clip_shapefile,
          'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
      })
      clipped_layer = result['OUTPUT']
      #Save the clipped layer to a shapefile
      QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(clipped_layer, output_shapefile, "UTF-8", clipped_layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")

      #Print debug information
      print(f"Depth band: {band}, Number of features: {clipped_layer.featureCount()}, Geometry type: {clipped_layer.geometryType()}")

print("Extraction and clipping completed.")
```

Comment: At risk of not actually answering the question, may I suggest trying the *Split Vector Layer* tool. It splits a layer based on values in a chosen field. It can of course be called from PyQGIS: `processing.run("native:splitvectorlayer", {params})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a filename on Windows with a `>` in it.

You could do something simple like change:

`band.replace(' ', '_')`

to

`band.replace(' ', '_').replace('>','_')`

and that would be sufficient to get you a valid filename.

The rest of the code works OK, though there is no need for the special logic for the `expr` for the `> 1.20` band.

`expr = QgsField("depth").name() + f" = '{band}'"` will work for all bands since `depth` is a text field.